# Lines Intersections by Drawing?

Tags: matlab, math, graphics, line, intersection

I'm drawing the following figure. The blue then the red lines are drawn with the `line` command. While I'm drawing a red line, is there a way to know if it intersects a blue line or not? I'm interested in computing the coordinates shown in green.

[image]

Comment: Since your blue `line` is not monotonic, and not a function, a usual approach based on `interp1` will not work. A foolproof way is to go along your `line` segment by segment, manually checking for crossing points, and determining the closest intersect for each red line. But I'm pretty sure there's a smarter, image-processing-based or visualization-based solution (I'm thinking raytracing or something similar).

Comment: I am thinking this is getting into the realm of computational geometry, line segment intersection algorithms, where one must worry about efficient traversal of all available line segments. I found a File Exchange implementation at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27205-fast-line-segment-intersection but have not tried this so I don't know if it will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @paisanco That function works really fast. Thanks. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the MATLAB Mapping toolbox, **polyxpoly** will work.

However if you do not, it is ultimately the problem of finding  (or coding your own) an implementation of an efficient line segment interaction algorithm from computational geometry.

For checking a few line segments, checking all pairs of linesegments using an interp1 based approach will do, but for checking many, that is not the most efficient approach since it is O(N^2) in N, the number of segment pairs. There are approaches that are more efficient that rely on presorting the list of line segments and excluding pairs that are too far apart. One discussion of such approaches is at:

[Sweep line intersection algorithm discussion by University of Illinois](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/373/notes/x06-sweepline.pdf)

For a MATLAB implementation, one option that may work for this problem is  available from the MATLAB File Exchange at:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27205-fast-line-segment-intersection

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`polyxpoly`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html), you just need to plug in the coordinates of your lines / the blue polygon.

Comment: This will work but does require the Mapping toolbox as far as I know.